# What is this piece of metal at my caliper?

Tags: kia, brake-calipers

This is the new caliper for my rear left wheel as seen from above, also when it's mounted to the car:

[image]

The cable of the parking brake is attached to the hook at the lower right, and the housing is hold by the angle bracket to the upper right, which is bolted to the caliper body.

Now, there is this big, massive, machined piece of metal attached to the angle bracket. It can't be a stop, since there is nothing that could stop there. It could be a counter weight, but this seems unlikely to me.

So, what is it?

(And yes, the old calipers have this too, on both sides.)

Edit: Kia Picanto 2004

Comment: What car is this? Make, model and year would help a lot

Answer (score 5):

I think you already figured it out.  Since it doesn't touch anything and the E-brake doesn't hook up to it, It is almost certainly a counterweight or dampner of some kind.  If the caliper doesn't weigh enough (or weighs too much), it can cuz squealing and juttering under load.  I can't find a link that corroborates this information, so-

As an example, the calipers on the early model Gen 5 Camaro didn't weigh enough, so the factory solution was to "stick some wheel weights on it" until **edit:** they added dampners to the back of the pads[image]